# Add two or more rows according to the some condition

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]
I want to merge rows with name and also merge category according to name column. I mean if Name column rows has same name then merge category data and rest of the data will be the same :

The output I want like this:
[image]

the goal is to remove duplicate according by the name and merge category column data into one column

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**
Code for multiple columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':["Call Building & Property Maintenance Ltd", "Call Building & Property Maintenance Ltd"],
'Category':['Fibreglass Roofing', 'Chimney Repairs'], 'Another_column':['Fibreglass Roofing', 'Chimney Repairs']})
df[['Category', 'Another_column']] = df.groupby('Name')[['Category', 'Another_column']].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))
df.drop_duplicates()
```

Output:

```
    Name    Category    Another_column
0   Call Building & Property Maintenance Ltd    Fibreglass Roofing,Chimney Repairs  Fibreglass Roofing,Chimney Repairs
```

Comment: that work but if we have more columns how we can do it?

Comment: The answer has been updated! @HarisAhmad